# RDLC stretch rectangle from header to footer (body height)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, height, rdlc, stretch

I'm gonna go crazy. I'm searching for a simple solution but it seems what I want isn't possible!? I have a Report with Header/Body/Footer. Inside the Body I had an Rectangle, next to an Tablix.

I want that this Rectangle is Auto-Stretched to full size of the body. So from top body to bottom body. The body area is flexible so has no fixed height. How can I achieve this? I tried every property of the rect, but still fail.

Maybe someone has the Solution as I searched 25+ Websites with no result.

Comment: To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you have that doesn't behave the way you're expecting it to.

Comment: Hi ti7,
there's no code as i'm designing the report with Visual Studio. I just using properties to set the behave. I don't know if it's possible to achieve it with code as i hadn't seen any solution yet. Not in Design or Code.